# GRUB won't always start when usb hdd present

Tags: 12.04, grub2, external-hdd

I have Ubuntu 12.04 dual boot with Windows 7 on my Dell XPS 17. I have following issue with my grub loader. When my usb hdd is pluged in, grub won't always load. I have to reset my laptop, and it may work without problem or it can fail. If I disconnect my hdd, and start laptop everything works great. My hdd is WesternDigital My Passport 500 GB with only one usb connection (no external power supply).

Does anyone know what could be the problem? It is not the biggest issue but it is a little annoying.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with the boot order of your machine, make sure it boots from the hdd before booting from a usb device. Boot order should be something like: 1 cdrom, 2 hdd, 3 usb, 4 networkboot. I hope this helps.

Comment: Great suggestion, that actually didn't occured to me to check. But my boot order is hdd, cdrom, usb, so that is not an issue. Anyway, thanks for help.